# Как из файла формата *.rpt считать данные?

Tags: c#

Нужно считать данные с файла формата *.rpt и затем используя эти данные построить график. Как лучше считать данные?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1) узнать в каком виде (или формате) хранятся там данные 2) написать программу, которая читает файл с заданным форматом 3) построить график на основе прочитанных из файлы данных

Comment: Формат данных windows1251

Comment: 1) *.rpt - это расширение 2) windows1251 - это кодировка 3) под форматом я имел ввиду, например, [следующее](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/pdf-file-format-basic-structure/) 4) но в вашем случае вроде как уже [все сделано за вас](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18329267/4041128). Т.е. вам остается только добавить нужный компонент и загрузить в него этот файл. 5) хотя я могу ошибаться и это не Crystal Report, поэтому придется вес-таки делать самостоятельно

Comment: Увы, но вы ошибаетесь.